# how to convert String 03/20/2019 10:46 to Date time in C#?

Tags: c#, string, datetime

i have a string 
 `03/20/2019 10:46` 
i want to convert to 
 datetime `03/20/2019 10:46:00 AM`  
i have tried to use but failed as i am getting exception 
 `convert.todatetime("03/20/2019 10:46")`  
 but i am getting format exception.

new into development need help.really confused what need to be done. i have also saw other question regarding this topic on stckoverflow but failed i have also used  
`datetime.parse` but still failed

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) method

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("03/20/2019 10:46", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Output:
3/20/2019 10:46:00 AM
```

POC : [.netFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZKJWnt)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
string dateTime = "03/20/2019 10:46";

DateTime parsedExactTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It´s missing the AM/PM though...